# How implement Leaky ReLU in Keras from scratch?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, activation, activation-function, relu

How to implement Leaky ReLU from scratch and use it as a custom function in Keras, I have a rough snippet but am not sure how close I am to the correct definition. My question comes in two parts:

1-*Is my implementation correct?*

2-*If not, what am I doing wrong?*

**The implementation am using:**

```
from keras import backend as K 
from keras.layers import Conv3D

def leaky_relu(x):
   alpha = 0.1
   return K.maximum(alpha*x, x)
```

**And usage :**

```
x = Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation=leaky_relu, padding='same', name='3D_conv')(x)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. I made a slight modification to the function to make it more reusable:

```
def LeakyReLU(alpha = 1):
    return lambda x : tf.keras.backend.maximum(alpha * x, x)
```

In this way, you could call the activation with different values of alpha:

```
x = Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation=LeakyReLU(0.1), padding='same', name='3D_conv')(x)
```